# OSB DB Polling - how to update multiple column during logical delete

Tags: osb

During logical delete of DB Polling process of OSB, I want to update a timestamp column **besides** the MarkReadColumn column.

Is there any way to do that? Can I modify the sql query for logical delete?

Best, Khalid

Comment: Have you tried to add a trigger directly in the database?

Comment: I could, but that will bypass the reason for using OSB :-)